# Short story about a scientist trying to prove faster-than-light travel with a billiard ball

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A short story about a scientist trying to prove faster than light travel. He uses a billiard ball for the demonstration. It works but the billiard ball passes through a rival scientist, killing said rival.

Comment: Actually it’s not about FTL travel but about proving anti-gravity. And then the effectively mass-less ball is not travelling FTL but *exactly* with the speed of light.

Comment: It's faster than the speed of light in air, which isn't what is meant by FTL, but does matter slightly to the story (Cherenkov radiation).

Comment: @armb I would argue it doesn't matter, because the author didn't really consider all the effects that a light-speed billiard ball would cause, even if massless (http://what-if.xkcd.com/1/), aka what happens to all the massive air particles in the way?

Comment: @Michael It matters a bit within the context of the story, because if the inventor hadn't just dismissed the blue glow when asked about it, he might not have gone ahead with the fatal demonstration.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

["The Billiard Ball"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Billiard_Ball) (1966) by Isaac Asimov.

It is written from a reporter's view. The reporter discusses the rivalry between the two men. The scientist is a slow theoretical thinker ("if you asked him if the Sun rose in the East, you could be certain that he had also considered the possibility that the Sun rose in the West"). The other is a fast practical thinker, an inventor.

The inventor asks the professor to try his invention, humiliating him - "even though he says it's impossible, he will now demonstrate it."

> The catch at the end of the story is, the billiard ball goes straight through the rival's heart - and the video footage shows that the scientist had already aimed the ball there! Had he, for once in his life, thought really fast and realized that the ball would work as a bullet?

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! I've been trying to remember this story for months :)

Comment: @tls You're welcome! Maybe I should thank _you_ - I'd never expected this to get so many upvotes!

Comment: I like how you put the spoiler text, even though the question contains the spoiler in plain text. ;)

Comment: @Michael, but it *might* be a little a different...don't spoil it...

Comment: @Michael Off the top of my head, the fact that the rival was dead was the opening of the story. The question gives away a bit, but the surprise in the story is in the last part of the first sentence in the spoiler block.

Comment: IIRC, the story is not about FTL travel but a machine that eliminates mass within a field.  The billiard ball is hit into this field, which is set up to run through a hole in the table.  Upon losing its mass the billiard ball acquires velocity _c_ (speed of light) and kills the rival.  Cute story, but I felt the ball would have done a lot more damage, I.e. destroying several square blocks, given the energy it "acquired".

Comment: @JimGarrison The energy would be liberated in a line roughly a mile long rather than as a point source.  While the total energy is about 1.5 megatons (I'm assuming Newtonian physics, otherwise you get nonsense) spreading it out like this is going to greatly cut it's destructive potential.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Everyone would really get a good radiation theraphy. OTOH, onc the ball exits Magical Field, it would reaquire its mass. As it hasn't obtained kinetic energy from nowhere, it would stop right there, falling on the billiard table as a heap of superfine dust.

Comment: I think it may be notable that the theory the possible murderer dismisses - is also the only one that would require billiard  genius at aiming a ball by taking the earth and galaxy's motion into  account. And makes more sense gravitationally. It was not moving at c from becoming massless but rather was at sudden absolute rest.    'The Earth's motion, after all, isn't the only motion involved, young man...If the billiard ball were subjected to zero gravity, you might think of it as being unaffected by any of these motions and therefore of suddenly falling into a state of absolute rest..."

Comment: This is one of the few stories that Asimov thought someone else had a better title for - Pohl suggested "Dirty Pool" (Asimov kept his own title, since he preferred to be consistent in using his own titles for better or worse).